# Create a regex to delete data in between

Tags: regex

I am having the below given data

```
Mr. SIM Kamsath, Vice President & Branch Manager
Tel: +855 (0)12 922 660, +855 (0)15 900 269
E-mail: getemail('acledabank.com.kh','kkg.bm%23')kkg.bm@acledabank.com.khMr. BUTH Veasna, Assistant Vice President & Manager of Marketing Officer
Tel: +855 (0)15 900 778
E-mail: getemail('acledabank.com.kh','buth.veasna%23')buth.veasna@acledabank.com.khStreet 48, Village 1, Sangkat Smach Mean Chey, Krong Khemrak Phument, Koh Kong Province, Cambodia.
P.O. Box: 1149
Tel: +855 (0)35 936 693 / 936 638, +855 (0)15 900 270
Fax: +855 (0)35 936 639
E-mail: getemail('acledabank.com.kh','kkg%23')kkg@acledabank.com.kh
SWIFT Code: ACLBKHPP
```

All I need from  this data is

```
khStreet 48, Village 1, Sangkat Smach Mean Chey, Krong Khemrak Phument, Koh Kong Province, Cambodia.
P.O. Box: 1149
Tel: +855 (0)35 936 693 / 936 638, +855 (0)15 900 270
```

I need to remove the rest of the part.

I tried regex as

```
E-mail[^<>]*
```

Other data on which the same regex should work

```
Mr. SIM Kamsath, Vice President & Branch Manager
Tel: +855 (0)12 922 660, +855 (0)15 900 269
E-mail: getemail('acledabank.com.kh','kkg.bm%23')kkg.bm@acledabank.com.khMr. BUTH Veasna, Assistant Vice President & Manager of Marketing Officer
Tel: +855 (0)15 900 778
E-mail: getemail('acledabank.com.kh','buth.veasna%23')buth.veasna@acledabank.com.khStreet 48, Village 1, Sangkat Smach Mean Chey, Krong Khemrak Phument, Koh Kong Province, Cambodia.
P.O. Box: 1149
Tel: +855 (0)35 936 693 / 936 638, +855 (0)15 900 270
Fax: +855 (0)35 936 639
E-mail: getemail('acledabank.com.kh','kkg%23')kkg@acledabank.com.kh
SWIFT Code: ACLBKHPP
```

Comment: Why you don't want the first email part?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using a third party tool and this data appears in the above format on a website

Comment: This other data is the same as the data you posted initially.

Comment: I don't know why you want `khStreet`, since `kh` is part of the preceding email address `buth.veasna@acledabank.com.kh`

Answer (score 1):

```
E-mail:(?=(?:(?!E-mail)[\s\S])*P.O. Box)\s\S*\.([\s\S]*?)(?=Fax)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/15

Comment: Thanks for the response but if I use the same code on the below mentioned data then its not working. Updating the content above

Comment: You provided the regex which removed the data which I required. output should be khStreet 48, Village 1, Sangkat Smach Mean Chey, Krong Khemrak Phument, Koh Kong Province, Cambodia.
P.O. Box: 114

Comment: I am not able to find it can you please provide me with the regex

Comment: The regex you provided is giving me the required portion but I need to eliminate the rest this is not working for me.

Comment: I cannot use replace there the only thing I can do is fetch the data using regex

Comment: I applied regex E-mail: getemail\('([^']*)','[^']*'\)([^@]*@\1) it removes the other portion then on that data I apply regex (?:(P.O. .*)\r?\n)? then I need to remove person name which is starting with Mr. I am stuck there

Comment: The only thing I can do here is remove the unnecessary texts and keep the portion which I require

Comment: How can I remove Mr. and then the name of the person?

Comment: I need to remove the whole line eg Mr. SIM Kamsath, Vice President & Branch Manager

Comment: One more question the regex E-mail: getemail\('([^']*)','[^']*'\)([^@]*@\1) is not helping me to remove data  E-mail: toch.bonboramy@acledabank.com.khMr. SOM Manil can you provide me updated one which removes data behind E-mail:

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not very clear what you want for the first entry, where E-mail line is not available. I assume you don't want to extract anything from the first entry.

```
E-mail: getemail\('([^']*)','[^']*'\)([^@]*@\1)(.+)?\r?\n(?:(P.O. .*)\r?\n)?(Tel: .*)?
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/oH3eO3/1) (I wrote the pattern to make it compatible with even JavaScript).

High level break down of the regex:

- `E-mail: getemail\('([^']*)','[^']*'\)([^@]*@\1)(.+)?\r?\n` matches the email line, and use the content from the argument to `getemail` as hint to separate the email from the text that comes after. **I assume there is no percentage escape in the string literal of `getemail`**.
- `(?:(P.O. .*)\r?\n)?` matches optional P.O. Box line
- `(Tel: .*)?` matches optional Tel line.

Capturing groups:

- Group 2 contains the email address.
- Group 3 contains the text after the email address.
- Group 4 contains the P.O. Box line.
- Group 5 contains the Tel line.

(I wrote group 3 as `(.+)?` to make the group return `null`/`undefined` when nothing follows the email address, instead of `(.*)` which will return an empty string).